# Fish: The file is not executable by this user

Tags: permissions, python, executable, fish

I made *fish function* in `~/.config/fish/functions/confgit.fish`:

```
function confgit
    /home/john/Projects/confgit $argv
end
```

But when I run this function it just says:

```
fish: The file “/home/john/Projects/./confgit” is not executable by this user  
    /home/john/Projects/./confgit $argv  
    ^  
in function 'confgit'
```

The config file is normal python script. If I run it by `./confgit` it runs fine.

There are the permissions of the script:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 john john 5.8K 29. nov 02.04 confgit*
```

How can I fix this so I can use this function ?
Thank you for help

Comment: Can you list or screenshot the permissions on the file for us?

Comment: @MarkScheck I have added permission info to question. Thank you for your reminder

Comment: Does `john` run this function or is it run by a service?

Comment: @Stewart The whole point of this function is that I would be able to run `confgit` script from anywhere. So this command will be exclusively run in terminal by me(user `john`).

Comment: What is the shebang line in `/home/john/Projects/confgit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked to reproduce your problem, and the closest thing I could emulate was this:

```
# file: ~/bin/janstest
echo $argv
```

```
# file: ~/bin/janstest2
function janstest
  ~/bin/janstest $argv
end

janstest It works!
```

and file permissions as:

```
stew@stewbian ~> ls -l ~/bin/jans*
-rwxr-xr-x /home/stew/bin/janstest*
-rwxr-xr-x /home/stew/bin/janstest2*
```

When I run it I get a similar error:

```
stew@stewbian ~> ~/bin/janstest2
Failed to execute process '/home/stew/bin/janstest2'. Reason:
exec: Exec format error
The file '/home/stew/bin/janstest2' is marked as an executable but could not be run by the operating system.
stew@stewbian ~ [125]>
```

The solution was to prepend `#!/usr/bin/fish` to the the script.

```
stew@stewbian ~> cat ~/bin/janstest2
#!/usr/bin/fish
function janstest
  ~/bin/janstest $argv
end

janstest It works
stew@stewbian ~> ~/bin/janstest2
It works
```

Comment: Thank for your answer

Comment: I hope it helps.  If it doesn't, see if you can make a skeleton script to emulate the problem.  If you can't reproduce, figure out the difference between your skeleton and your actual script.